# Filter in separate file throws unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I generate the following file (slice.js):

```
function slice ($scope) {
   return function(arr, start, end) {
       return arr.slice(start, end)
   }
}

angular
   .module('loop')
   .filter('slice', slice)
```

in my directive template I call the filter

```
div(ng-repeat="(periodKey,period) in periods | slice:start:end").col
```

and I get the unnow provider error.

But when i define the filter in my app.js like this

```
app.filter('slice', function() {
   return function(arr, start, end) {
      return arr.slice(start, end);
   };
});
```

There is no error and it works fine. Can you help me to solve the problem please?

Thanks!

Comment: remove `$scope` from the parameters of your `slice` function

Comment: works fine...can you help me to understand this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$scope` from the parameters of your slice function.

Angular expects to inject a service there, and there is no service provider for the service called `$scope` (obviously). Read here about [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#factory-methods) in Angular